# Inline dimming circuit fed from dimmable lighting controller

Tags: dimming, lighting

I have an industrial dimmable lighting controller (240VAC, 50Hz) which has one output going to a splitter cable with multiple connectors, where many dimmable LED tubes can be connected.

I would like to know whether it would be technically possible fit another dimming system (i.e. TRIAC, MOSFET) to one of these connectors and then connect an LED tube to the output of this secondary dimming system. If it is possible, what are the pitfalls of this? Could this work in a flicker-free manner (i.e. some kind of trailing edge MOSFET solution)?

The idea here is that the primary lighting controller would be responsible for setting the overall maximum brightness level of the system (and also control the brightness of the directly connected LED tubes,) with the inline dimming solution providing an individual brightness level up to the maximum brightness level.

Replacing the original industrial lighting controller is not an option here.

Would it also be the case that when the primary lighting controller is set to, say 80% brightness and any inline solution is set to 50% "of maximum", that its brightness would be 40% - or would any relationship here be non-linear?

Comment: Easiest way to feed secondary dimmer before primary. Additional pair or even one wire should be used. But you may try your way, post the results. With different types of dimmers you may get different results.

Comment: The primary lighting controller is hard-wired in, the only point at which this secondary system can be added is to one of the splitter connectors. I will source two trailing-edge dimmers and wire them up in series to see what happens - ultimately the second dimmer will be MCU/IoT controlled so I'll see if there is an Arduino-style dimmer which I could use for my tests. Thanks. Will post back with my findings.